# Method recommendation for Implementing notify counts in Symfony2 way

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony2 application that consists of several bundles.
The application has a `DashboardBundle` & I need to show the count of unread contents of each bundle in `DashboardBundle`'s template.
What is the correct Symfony way to do this?

- Create a service to count each entity of each bundle?
- Create a twig extension to do so?
- Implement this in custom repository of each entity?
- Use The main bundle's controller & embed it `DashboardBundle`'s template?
- Count everything in `DashboardBundle`'s controller and pass it to template?
- Something else?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "contents of each bundle" ? Are you talking about a notification system ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen: for example if it is a message bundle, the count of unread messages & if it is the user bundle , the count of unchecked users; yes some sort of notification but only with a number next to each section (e.g. a number next to messaging section that shows unread messages)

Comment: You should implement a notification system then, each user would have related notifications in the database that you can mark them as read or unread. IMHO the best way to achieve it is to hook on events for adding the notifications.